# Can you turn subsets of slides into a custom component in Ionic 3+?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have tried to create custom components which are subsets of slides. I'm trying to create a custom Ionic component which is a subset of slides. Then I can mix and match subsets of slides in one  to make a complete slide show. Like building a master process from sub-processes. You should be able to swipe back and forth between all slides as expected, no matter an  directly in the  component, or slides within custom components.

I've tried various methods to no avail. Any ideas?

[**PLEASE SEE THIS SAMPLE PROJECT WITH 2 METHODS I HAVE TRIED TO ACCOMPLISH THIS.**](https://github.com/jtittler/slider-test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't do this. You can put a  into another  if one scrolls vertically and one horizontally. You can insert a custom component into an  which just has a couple slides in it, put the inserted slides show one over the other vertically with no way to swipe back and forth. So, no. You can't do this. Perhaps with dynamic templates you can build the  from code dynamically. That's the only work around I can see.